# Confusion with structure variable in C++

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

Is it possible to assign value of one structure variable to another structure variable
Is this code correct -

```
#include<iostream.h>
struct s1
{
    int a;
    float b;
    char c;
}   st1,st2,st3;
int main()
{
    struct s2{
            int x;
            float y;
            char z;
        }   ss1,ss2,ss3;
        // Read & Initialize structures 
        ss2=ss1;
        :
        ss3.z=st1.c;
           :
}
void func1()
{
    ss2.x=st1.a;
    ss3.y=st2.b;
    ss1.z=st3.c;
       :
    ss1=ss3;
}
```

Kindly clear my doubt whether the above code is OK or not

Comment: What about _'asking'_ the compiler? Note that [tag:turboc++] is a stoneage compiler, that might give you wrong or misleading answers!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about asking questions any decent modern c++ compiler will immediately clarify!

Comment: Why the turbo bit - it did not have a turbo! Bit like countries calling themselves democratic

Comment: In school in class 7 we have to use Turbo C++ for learning C++

Comment: @Vishal - Just download g++ and linux. Where do you come from?

Comment: @EdHeal India and here in school we use Turbo C++ for learning computer language as toddler

Comment: @Vishal - Please download g++. You email address is on me profile and I think you will go far. Email me if you need any help

Comment: I could never understand what the schools' problem with GCC is. It's completely free and leaps and bounds ahead of Turbo. Why would you deliberately screw up so many people's programming education like that?

Comment: @chris -Perhaps that is what the tutor learned and is comfortable with

Comment: @Vishal Nothing hinders you to ask [Ideone](http://ideone.com/lpCAuo) though ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ This is my favorite site for testing my codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ss2=ss1; this will depend on the compiler some compiler will allow to copy the structure variable and some not.
  ss2.x=st1.a; ss2 structure will be local to the main function and it is not available in funct1(), so it must be throwing the compilation error.

Comment: Thank you considering my problem. You are right throwing compilation error. That means I can use `ss2.x=st1.a;` if compiler allow

Comment: to use ss2 structure in funct1() you should declare struct      struct s2{
            int x;
            float y;
            char z;
        }   ss1,ss2,ss3;  above the main